# Как выполнить SQL-запрос к двум таблицам в одном запросе?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы. Первая - **tickets_pages**:

```
 origin | destination | isvaluable |  expirity
--------+-------------+------------+------------
 moscow | paris       | t          | 2018-12-11
```

Вторая - **snapshots**:

```
 id  | pathname               | html | inserted   | affiliation
-----+------------------------+------+------------+-------------
 123   /tickets/moscow/paris/   ...    1541369402   f
```

Что мне нужно: сделать запрос в таблицу **tickets_pages**, а затем присоединить к ответу значение поля `inserted` из таблицы snapshots. Итого должен получиться такой ответ:

```
 origin | destination | isvaluable | expirity   | inserted 
--------+-------------+------------+------------+------------
 moscow | paris       | t          | 2018-12-11   1541369402
```

Посоветуйте, какие SQL-операторы мне нужны и в какую сторону копать?

Comment: JOIN. А копать в сторону формирования точного условия соответствия записей.

Comment: У вас единственная связь между таблицами - это значения подстрок в поле `pathname`?

Comment: я бы для начала добавил в таблицу tickets_pages внешний ключ на таблицу snapshots, а потом просто делаем объединение таблиц по ключу.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev наличие таблицы `tickets_pages` не предполагалось на ранней стадии. Сейчас переделываю определённый алгоритм и появилась необходимость брать данные из новой таблицы вместе с данными со старой.